# Dual display setup not working on Windows 7 Pro with HP

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

I am completely unable to get a second display working on a Windows 7 Pro machine.

The HP motherboard has an additional DVI output, and I have tried using this with a VGA converter, and nothing displays.

I have also tried using a U3-VIEW USB3 to VGA converter, and this crashes the entire machine when one tries to install the drivers. I am using the exact same adapter on another machine, and it works perfectly.

I have updated all drivers, and performed OS updates, although one update that appears to be graphics adapter related does not want to install.

I am completely stumped here, and I would greatly appreciate any help, as I am trying to avoid doing an OS reinstall.

Below are some screenshot links for reference.

DirectX Diagnostic tool:

[image: DirectX diagnostics tool]

System Information:
[image: System information]

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows Key + P?

Comment: @Stephen yes, the monitor was still not available. Apologies for the slow response. I haven't had much time to attend to this. I did a clean OS install on a separate drive in that machine, and the issue persisted. Must be hardware related. I don't think the onboard graphics is capable of supporting duel displays.